# How to get deleted documents from DeleteMany middleware in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an application in which I manage `categories` and `subcategories`.
So each time I delete a `category`, I have a mongoose middleware that deletes all the `subcategories` who belong to it.

```
schema.post('findOneAndDelete',
    (category: CategoryDocument) => subcategoryModel.deleteMany({ category: category.id }))
```

That works fine when I delete just one `category`, what happens when I delete multiple?
I tried registering a `deleteMany` middleware like so:

```
schema.post('deleteMany',
            (deletedQueryResult: any) => {})
```

But the `deleteMany` middleware just sends to my callback the result of the query (the time it took, number of deleted documents and some internal mongoose/mongodb properties).

Is there anyway I can get the deleted documents or their ids inside a mongoose middleware?
If not what are my other options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deleteMany` method returns an object with three fields:

- `n` – number of matched documents
- `ok` – `1` if the operation was successful, else 0
- `deletedCount` – number of deleted documents

This is the same behaviour of the mongodb [`db.collection.deleteMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) method.

I suggest you to add a [static method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) to your model:

```
// Assign a function to the "statics" object of our schema
categorySchema.statics.deleteManyWithSubs = async function(catIds) {
  const deleteQuery = /*your delete query using catIDs*/
  const delRes = await this.deleteMany(deleteQuery);
  catIds.forEach(id => {
     await subcategoryModel.deleteMany({ category: id })
  });
  return true;
};

// Usage
categoryModel.deleteManyWithSubs(ids)...
```